# How to get JMETER Load Testing Accurately With multiple webservice (pods)

Tags: kubernetes, jmeter, load-testing, kubernetes-pod, jmeter-3.2

I am new to JMeter Load testing. We have installed a distributed JMeter Load testing in EC2 AWS, with 1 master and 5 slaves.
So I am testing my web service endpoint (HTTP Request) in JMeter.

**Details:**

1. Tested my web service and reached 1900 threads with 0% error percentage in 1 pod with 8Gi RAM.
2. Now, I deployed my web service in 2 pods (replicas) with 8Gi RAM, however it is having more than 0% error percentage even my threads was set **ONLY** to 2100.
3. Did check the logs, there is no error, did check the pods health it was alright, did check the Database CPU utillization and it was alright.

Our expectation is that, since we have 2 pods already, it can accomodate x2 of 1900 threads (just like what happened in 1 pod).
Did I miss something to check? I hope someone could give me some light :(
It has been bugging me for 12 hours now.

Thank you in advance.